# Select multiple columns for each date

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table 'Messages' which holds a timestamp and events as strings. I want to display how many different events happened in the last 30 days.

So the output should like:

```
date          event_1       event_2
...
2017-08-01          4             0
2017-08-02          0             0
2017-08-03          5             3
2017-08-04          0             2
...
```

Important is that every day (even if no event at all occur) will be displayed.

My code looks like:

```
SELECT distinct(DATE(MESSAGE.DATEFIELD)) as 'date',
IF(MESSAGE.EVENT = 'event_1', COUNT(MESSAGE.ID), 0) AS 'event 1',
IF(MESSAGE.EVENT = 'event_2', COUNT(MESSAGE.ID), 0) AS 'event 2'
FROM MESSAGE
WHERE DATE(MESSAGE.DATEFIELD) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY date, MESSAGE.EVENT
```

This does not work. It adds multiple days for each event. Can you point me my mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DATEFIELD, 
count(case when EVENT = 'event_1' then 1 end) AS 'event 1',
count(case when EVENT = 'event_2' then 1 end) AS 'event 2'
from message
WHERE DATE(MESSAGE.DATEFIELD) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
group by DATEFIELD
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks